# Unresponding program on a low level standpoint

Tags: cpu, crash, scheduling

When a program doesn't respond, on a low level (maybe even down to cpu instructions), what exactly happens? Does the cpu scheduler fail to get a response from the cpu on whether the program executed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cpu knows nothing about "programs". If cpu instructions do not operate correctly, there is
a hardware failure, not a software (program) failure. Program non-response refers to a buggy
program not behaving as expected, e.g., not responding to OS window messages, or failing
to clear i/o completion interrupts, or getting stuck in an infinite loop, etc.